# How to embed PHP powered blog in subdirectory of Rails 5 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails powered website running on `www.myapp.com`.

Now my boss asked me to add a **blog** to that website. The number of blog articles is expected to grow strongly over the next few years, possibly into the hundreds or even thousands.

The problem: Our Rails app is not suited for content production or blogging at all!

My boss has a [PHP / XML powered software](http://www.getsymphony.com) in mind that he wants me to install for the purpose of running the blog. But the software has nothing in common with Ruby on Rails and cannot be combined with it.

Now we figured that setting up the blog under a subdomain like `blog.myapp.com` would be feasible. However, according to various sources this may come at the price of less search engine visibility when compared with running the blog in a subdirectory of our website such as `www.myapp.com/blog/` which would be our favourite solution.

So to cut a long story short, is there a way to establish a PHP blog in a subdirectory of a Rails 5 app? If so, how?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Did you consider putting a load balancer in front of your servers? Configure it to point routes starting with `/blog` to a server running the blog and all other routes to your Rails application servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd configure this in your frontend web server (Apache, nginx, etc.).  Normally, you pass all requests to your domain to your Rack server (Unicorn, Puma, etc.).  Instead, you want to treat /blog as your PHP app - configuring all URLs with that path to run your PHP, and pass all *other* URLs to your upstream Rack server as you would for any other Rails app.  Specifics on how to implement this would depend on what frontend web server you're using.